# Don't know how to insert those data in a blank td

Tags: php, mysqli, html-table

I'm not really good in PHP. How to insert those data in a blank `td`?

[image: Output HERE..]

I don't know what to change..

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $date = date_create($row['datebor']);
 echo date_format($date,'F d, Y');   
 $output .= ' 
 <tr>  
                     <td>'.$row["badgenum"].'</td>
                     <td>'.$row["itemnameb"].'</td>
                     <td>'.$row["quantity"].'</td>
                     <td>'.$row["statusb"].'</td>
                     <td>'.'</td>
                     <td>'.$row["dateret"].'</td>  
                     <td>'.$row["badgenumret"].'</td>
                </tr>
 ';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the echo, and inserted the value of `$date` to `<td>..</td>`

**Try:**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $date = date_create($row['datebor']);
  $date = date_format($date,'F d, Y');   
  $output .= ' 
   <tr>  
                     <td>'.$row["badgenum"].'</td>
                     <td>'.$row["itemnameb"].'</td>
                     <td>'.$row["quantity"].'</td>
                     <td>'.$row["statusb"].'</td>
                     <td>'.$date.'</td>
                     <td>'.$row["dateret"].'</td>  
                     <td>'.$row["badgenumret"].'</td>
                </tr>';
}
```